# How to get the last 2 bits in a byte

Tags: javascript, image-processing

In an array of bytes, such as `[40, 0, 156, 243]`, I need to make 1 byte from the last two bits in each byte of the array. This is for decoding and encoding PICO-8 cartridges ([see here](http://www.lexaloffle.com/pico-8.php)), which stores the program data in PNG images. Here is the information that I've been given on how the data is stored:

`For png files, the lower 2 bits of each pixel component makes up one byte, so 1 byte per pixel. The last 32 bytes are metadata for the PNG (since 160*205 = 0x8020, 32 extra bytes)
byte = (a << 6) | (r << 4) | (g << 2) | b;`

Here's what I have so far, but the output is all gibberish:

```
var imgWidth  = 160;
var imgHeight = 205;
var canvas    = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx       = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img       = document.createElement('img');

img.src = 'Invasion.png';

canvas.width  = imgWidth;
canvas.height = imgHeight;

img.onload = function() {
  var imgData = [];
  var str     = '';
  var i = 0, n = 0, dataLen = 0;

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight).data;
  dataLen = imgData.length;

  for(i; i < dataLen; i+=4) {
    var r = imgData[i];
    var g = imgData[i + 1];
    var b = imgData[i + 2];
    var a = imgData[i + 3];

    r = (r & 3) << 4;
    g = (g & 3) << 2;
    b = (b & 3);
    a = (a & 3) << 6;

    byte = a | r | g | b; // assembled byte

    str += String.fromCharCode(byte);
  }

  console.log(str);
};
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24o3fzg3/

Greatly appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last two bits, try `value & 3` rather than `value % 100`. (`value % 100` takes the remainder of `value` after dividing by 100 in decimal, not binary.) You then need to shift those two bits into the appropriate position in the final byte. Something like this:

```
  r = (pixels[n][0] & 3) << 4;
  g = (pixels[n][1] & 3) << 2;
  b = (pixels[n][2] & 3);
  a = (pixels[n][3] & 3) << 6;

  val = a | r | g | b; // assembled byte
```

(I'm not addressing whether this is the correct order for the bits in the assembled value or the correct pixel array order.)

Comment: I'm assuming this is definitely closer to correct than what I had, however I'm still getting gibberish output for some reason. I know that the data is not compressed in any way. I've changed the order around multiple ways, and surprisingly it doesn't seem to make a difference what order they are in, as the output is exactly the same. If it helps, all the values are now coming out as 0, 1, 2, or 3 (which doesn't seem right).

Comment: Ok, I was doing something wrong, but it still isn't right. `console.log(r, g, b, a)` now looks like this: `16 0 0 192`, but `str` is still gibberish.

Comment: How string should be like in this case?

Comment: Maybe value must stored as hex string? str += val.toString(16);

Comment: @ChrisClower - I suspect a bookkeeping error of some sort. Is there any reason for the complicated `pixels` array handling? Why not get rid of `pixels` and just index directly into `imgData` to get 4 byte values from an offset that increases by 4 at each iteration? Also, what does the input (`imgData`) look like?

Comment: I've amended the code in my question above to reflect your suggestion, which was a great one (the pixels array was originally there so I could make sure the length of it matched the number of pixels in the image, so I could see that I was getting all of them; I just never removed it). Here's my project if you want to play with the files: http://clowerweb.com/games/pico/picoder-test.zip - index.html has my js in it, the PNG image in the folder what I'm trying to decode, and the .p8 file is just a text file that the image was made from (the decoded data should look like this). Thanks so much!

Comment: I made a Fiddle if you don't want to download the .zip folder: https://jsfiddle.net/24o3fzg3/

Comment: @ChrisClower - Well, the gobbledygook is hardly surprising. It's basically dumping the raw data as characters. Try pavnik's suggestion: replace `str += String.fromCharCode(a | r | g | b);` with `str += (a | r | g | b).toString(16);`. The output will then be a hex dump of the data and look a lot more sensible.

Comment: @TedHopp The output does look much better, but unfortunately it's still not correct. I know it's not compressed or encrypted in any way, so even if it does look better, I'm not sure whether it actually IS closer to correct or not.

Comment: @ChrisClower - Perhaps you can look at a few bytes of the input data and check by hand. Or you could dump the data and process it in some other way to produce an actual image to compare with the original. But now we're really moving out of the scope of this particular question. If you can't figure it out, I suggest posting a new question on SO.

Comment: Ok, I've looked over all the output data and it's actually very close! In the original text file, the first 48 bytes of graphics data begins with `00000000000000000000000000777700000000000700007`, and in the decoded version, it looks like this: `000000000000077770000070007000007070000070000200`. There's definitely a similar pattern here, but it looks like our decoded data is missing a bunch of 0s for some reason... I've gone ahead and accepted the answer since it is the correct answer to the question regardless of the output being unexpected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisClower - Okay! Good luck with the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a not an js guy, but I think code should be like this:

```
...
r = (pixels[n][0] & 3);
g = (pixels[n][1] & 3);
b = (pixels[n][2] & 3);
a = (pixels[n][3] & 3);
byte = (a << 6) | (r << 4) | (g << 2) | b;
str += String.fromCharCode(byte);
...
```